# Shell Script that performs different functions based on input from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to merge two very different scripts together for consolidation and ease of use purposes.  I have an idea of how I want these scripts to look and operate, but I could use some help getting started.  Here is the flow and look of the script:

The input file would be a standard text file with this syntax:

```
#Vegetables
Broccoli|Green|14
Carrot|Orange|9
Tomato|Red|7

#Fruits
Apple|Red|15
Banana|Yellow|5
Grape|Purple|10
```

The script would take the input of this file.  It would ignore the commented portions, but use them to dictate the output.  So based on the fact that it is a Vegetable, it would perform a specific function with the values listed between the delimiter (|).  Then it would go to the Fruits and do something different with the values, based on that delimiter.  Perhaps, I would add Vegetable/Fruit to one of the values and dependent on that value it would perform the function while in this loop to read the file.  Thank you for your help in getting this started.

UPDATE:
So I am trying to implement the IFS setup and thought of a more logical arrangement.  The input file will have the "categories" displayed within the parameters.  So the setup will be like this:

```
Vegetable|Carrot|Yellow
Fruit|Apple|Red
Vegetable|Tomato|Red
```

From there, the script will read in the lines and perform the function.  So basically this type of setup in shell:

```
while read -r category item color
do
    if [[ $category == "Vegetable" ]] ; then
        echo "The $item is $color"
    elif [[ $category == "Fruit" ]] ; then
        echo "The $item is $color"
    else
        echo "Bad input"
 done < "$input_file"
```

Something along those lines...I am just having trouble putting it all together.

Comment: Probably useful to use `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Use read to input the lines. Do a case statement on their prefix:

```
{
  while read DATA; do
    case "$DATA" in
       \#*) ... switch function ...;;
         *) eval "$FUNCTION";;
    esac
  done
} <inputfile
```

Dependent on your problem you might want to experiment with setting $IFS before reading and read multiple variables in 1 go.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the processing function each time you meet a `#` directive:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read line ; do
    if [[ $line == '#Vegetables' ]] ; then
        process () {
            echo Vegetables: "$@"
        }
    elif [[ $line == '#Fruits' ]] ; then
        process () {
            echo Fruits: "$@"
        }
    else
        process $line
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Note that the script does not skip empty lines.

Comment: That is awesome.  Thank you.  And what is the syntax to use the values in between the | delimiter as variables?  Haven't been able to find a decent example.

Comment: @user2317377: If you set `IFS='|'`, the shell will do the hard work for you. Just do not forget to do so in a subshell, or set the value back to its original value.